# Button for delete the values of my fields

Tags: php

I have 2 fields (pseudo et level) in my form. I have a button "confirm" which validates my values in my 2 fields. Now I would like to create a button which empties/cancels the values of my 2 fields. 
Is it possible ? I don't know how to do that.

Here is my code for information

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php 

    if($code_error != 0)
    {
        echo $message; 
    }

    echo '<form action="index.php" method="GET" >';
    echo '<label for="pseudo">Pseudo: </label>';
    if(isset($_GET['pseudo']))
    {
        echo '<input type="text" id="pseudo" name="pseudo" value="'.$_GET['pseudo'].'">'; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<input type="text" id="pseudo" name="pseudo">';
    }

    echo '<br/><br/>';
    echo '<label for="level">Level : </label>';
    if(isset($_GET['level']))
    {
        echo '<input type="text" id="level" name="level" value="'.$_GET['level'].'" >';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<input type="text" id="level" name="level" >';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="confirm">'; 

    echo '</form>';


  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reset button to clear all inputs value

```
echo "<input type='reset' value='Reset'>";
```

Comment: Source docs, if interested:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset